# My style.css get overwritten by wordpress default style.min.css

Tags: wordpress

I'm struggling since a while with styles in WordPress.

What happens is that I define a style for a Block in `my.css` and in the website, this style gets overwritten by the `style.min.css`. So if WordPress want's the color to be green by default, I can just force it to change this by putting !important everywhere. That's super ugly.

```
function wpdocs_theme_name_scripts() {
    wp_enqueue_style( 'style.css', get_stylesheet_uri() );
}
add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'wpdocs_theme_name_scripts' );
```

That is how I load my standard `style.css` in my self-written theme in WordPress 5.3.2.

So if anyone knows, how I can tell WordPress to load my `style.css` after the style.min.css or whatever causes this inconvenience.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Use [CSS Specificity](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Specificity) to assign higher priority to your CSS rules.**

Ironically, your desire to "*keep selectors as short and basic as possible*" is working against you, but the provided link will help you build high-priority, specific, CSS Selectors.

NOTE: Wordpress is NOT "*overwriting*" your .css file. We know this because your CSS applies when you add `!important` to the rules -- so, the CSS rules must be loaded, hence this is a CSS priority issue, not a Wordpress issue. Also, note that CSS rules never "*overwrite*" eachother; instead, all rules are there, but only one is used (typically, the most specific one).

Answer (score 0):

Change your `style.css` parameter to `your-theme-style-css`

Answer (score 0):

After experimenting around, I slowly believe, that the problems roots are in css itself. ".wp-block-cover .wp-block-cover__inner-container" is the wordpress class. My class is just ".wp-block-cover__inner-container", as I prefer to keep selectors as short and basic as possible.
But if I change my class name to the exact same, used by WordPress as well, it is working. Also if I just put any other class in front, the styles are applying properly.

So it seems for me now to be a priority question from CSS. Is this possible?